# Clojure butlast vs drop-last

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

What is the difference between [`butlast`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/butlast) and [`drop-last`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/drop-last) in Clojure ?

Is it only the laziness ? Should I should prefer one over the other ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

also, if you need to realize the whole collection, `butlast` is dramatically faster, which is logical if you look at their source:

```
(def 
 butlast (fn ^:static butlast [s]
           (loop [ret [] s s]
             (if (next s)
               (recur (conj ret (first s)) (next s))
               (seq ret)))))

(defn drop-last
  ([s] (drop-last 1 s))
  ([n s] (map (fn [x _] x) s (drop n s))))
```

so `drop-last` uses `map`, while `butlast` uses simple iteration with `recur`. Here is a little example:

```
user> (time (let [_ (butlast (range 10000000))]))
"Elapsed time: 2052.853726 msecs"
nil

user> (time (let [_ (doall (drop-last (range 10000000)))]))
"Elapsed time: 14072.259077 msecs"
nil
```

so i wouldn't blindly prefer one over another. I use `drop-last` only when i really need laziness, otherwise `butlast`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, laziness as well as the fact that `drop-last` can take also take `n`, indicating how many elements to drop from the end lazily.

There's a discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/ymcTsMeNKfU) where someone is making the case that `butlast` is more readable and maybe a familiar idiom for Lisp programmers, but I generally just opt to use `drop-last`.